# Can we have multiple react versions in node modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, node-modules

I am getting the following error while using a react component - react-avatar-editor

**A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.**

My main project has the react version 0.13.3 and the node module (react-avatar-editor) has the react version 0.14.1 , Could it be due to this?

Are we allowed to use a different react version in node modules , What is the alternative to fix it?

Comment: Change the version of react in your package.json file. As of 0.14 your component can return null. 15.0 was just released as well.

Comment: I cannot change the version of my main project as it has dependencies with other modules . Any alternative to use 0.14 with 0.13??

Comment: Yeah, I also want a solution for this as I am currently using `"react-native": "0.61.5",`, however, the package `mem` requires react-native 0.57...